# Magento 2.4: Pass jQuery value into checkout_cart_product_add_after observer

Tags: magento2, event-observer, addtocart, jquery

I have done some custom price calculation on product page using jQuery and I want to add the calculated price to the product during addtocart event.

Any help would be appreciated.